# AJAX POST object to controller with 2 date values, one date value wrong? asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

id like to pass from date and to date from view to AJAX and then POST to controller, in AJAX all the values seem to be fine, but in controller one date value gets 1.01.0001 value while other remains okay. Both dates with same structure in html and model.

```
  $('form').submit(function () {

    var form = $(this);
    var _data = {
        'vm': form.serialize()
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Home/GetFeedList',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(_data),
        success: function (s) {

            console.log('success' + s)
        },
        error: function (e) { console.log('something went wrong!', e, _data) }
    });
});
```

[image: toDate gets value while fromDate doesnt]

Html part just in case:

```
<h4>Period</h4>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="FromDate" class="form-control" id="from_date"  contenteditable="false" placeholder="From" />                
                <span asp-validation-for="FromDate" class="text-danger"></span>             
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="ToDate" class="form-control" id="to_date" contenteditable="false" placeholder="To" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ToDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to set ´form.serialize()´ as data parameter, then both date values got set.